# Volatile keyword not behaving as expected when used on int variable

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();        
        for (int  i =0; i<10 ; i++)
            arr.add(new MyTh(i));   
        for (int  i =0; i<10 ; i++) {
            ((Thread ) arr.get(i)).start();
        }
    }

}

class MyTh extends Thread {

   int num;

   volatile int  age;

   MyTh (int  k)

   {this.num=k; } 
   @Override
   public void run() {
    if(this.num==4){
        setAge(40);
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " :"+this.num + ":" + getAge());
}
    synchronized int getAge() {
       return age;
    }
    synchronized void  setAge(int  k) {
        this.age =k;
    }
}
```

I am puzzled here why the output of the program is  printing value of  volatile variable age   = 40 only once .
I tried  keeping  synchronized  in getter / setter both , then too only single  thread  4th  prints it 40 . Why not other subsequent thread read it 40 too ?

```
Thread-0 :0:0
Thread-1 :1:0
Thread-2 :2:0
Thread-3 :3:0
Thread-4 :4:40
Thread-5 :5:0
Thread-6 :6:0
Thread-7 :7:0
Thread-8 :8:0
Thread-9 :9:0
```

Comment: age is a local variable in every myth

Answer (score 1):

Why you use `synchronized` keyword for getters and setters while your variable is declared `volatile`. It is not needed here. You just need the visibility, not atomicity. So change your code like so,

```
public class MyTh extends Thread {
    int num;

    static volatile int age;

    MyTh(int k)

    {
        this.num = k;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (this.num == 4) {
            setAge(40);
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " :" + this.num + ":" + getAge());
    }

    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    void setAge(int k) {
        age = k;
    }
}
```

First mark the `age` variable as `static` so that the same is shared among all the instances of the class. In your previous case it was an instance field, hence each instance had it's own copy. Hence change made by one is not visible to the others.

Latest output is given below.

```
Thread-0 :0:0
Thread-3 :3:0
Thread-2 :2:0
Thread-1 :1:0
Thread-4 :4:40
Thread-6 :6:40
Thread-8 :8:40
Thread-5 :5:40
Thread-7 :7:40
Thread-9 :9:40
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you intend to have your age as a static variable.

```
static volatile int age;
```

Comment: static ( anyway is once per class ) it has strict single copy among  each instance  . Then why to use volatile  ?  I can go ahead  using static only .

Comment: Although it's shared amongst the instances, it may be cached by the instances. Subsequent update to the value may not be reflected. http://www.zrzahid.com/static-vs-volatile-in-java/

Comment: @tanyehzheng volatile usage is a whole waste in this example

Comment: @snr depending on the use case. Since it's asking about volatile, I believe it's the 2 synchronized keywords that are wasted.

Comment: Hi , i used synchronized afterwards , just to check if that may make any difference  . But  it's not required . I made few more modification to understand  where to use  the volatile keyword so that it can justify its existence . But unable to understand .

Comment: Here is  where the latest program  with static and shared volatile .https://void-summary.blogspot.com/ Printing there hashcode too to check if that is same object . I am really not understanding  what volatile  can not do what static can do OR vice versa . Why not to remove volatile  ? use static  too  enforces same and single copy.

Answer (score 0):

You have instance copy of age , Hence it is not shared copy , Use static keyword to make age class variable ,

Try below code What you want I guess

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

public class MyTh extends Thread
{
    int num;

```
static volatile int age;

MyTh(int k)

{
    this.num = k;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    if (this.num == 4)
    {
        setAge(40);
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " :" + this.num + ":" + getAge());
}

synchronized int getAge()
{
    return age;
}

synchronized void setAge(int k)
{
    this.age = k;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr.add(new MyTh(i));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ((Thread) arr.get(i)).start();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I used only static without  volatile  and got  Thread-0 :0:0
Thread-1 :1:0
Thread-2 :2:0
Thread-4 :4:40
Thread-3 :3:40
Thread-5 :5:40
Thread-6 :6:40
Thread-7 :7:40
Thread-8 :8:40
Thread-9 :9:40   ==> what purpose volatile has   when static can do the same for us.

Comment: @summary The `volatile` keyword enforces each thread to update their chached valued of the 'marked' variable before using it. This ensure that the most recent value will be used. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655412/a-simple-java-multithread) is good example why the `volatile` is crucial for a correct programm flow.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you are using [instance variable instead of class variable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293478/what-are-the-differences-between-class-variables-and-instance-variables-in-java). Your intend needs latter one.

Secondly, you don't need to use `volatile` keyword in your code because you use already `synchronized` on its getter/setter. [Here is its reason.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862226/java-is-volatile-required-with-synchronized)

Moreover, so that you have synchronization problem with modifying `arr`, you should use a mechanism to overcome it e.g. `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. Here is some problematic output examples,

```
Thread-9 :9:40
Thread-6 :6:40
Thread-1 :1:0
Thread-8 :8:40
Thread-4 :4:40
Thread-2 :2:0
Thread-5 :5:40
Thread-7 :7:40
Thread-3 :3:40 // <---- ???
Thread-0 :0:0

Thread-1 :1:0
Thread-3 :3:0  // <----
Thread-8 :8:40
Thread-7 :7:40
Thread-5 :5:40
Thread-6 :6:40
Thread-2 :2:0
Thread-4 :4:40
Thread-0 :0:0
Thread-9 :9:40

Thread-1 :1:40   // <---- ??? woww
Thread-3 :3:40   // <---- ??? woww  
Thread-8 :8:40   // <----  ok
Thread-7 :7:40   // <----  ok
Thread-5 :5:40   // <----  ok
Thread-6 :6:40   // <----  ok
Thread-2 :2:40   // <---- ??? woww
Thread-4 :4:40   // <----  ok
Thread-0 :0:0
Thread-9 :9:40   // <----  ok
```

**The problem here is that** operations of `ArrayList` is not synchronized, not thread safe. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` can be used to achieve that.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CopyOnWriteArrayList<Thread> arr = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

        for (int  i =0; i<10 ; i++)
            arr.add(new MyTh(i));

        for (int  i =0; i<10 ; i++) {
            (arr.get(i)).start();
        }
    }

}

class MyTh extends Thread {

    int num;
    static /*volatile*/ int  age;

    MyTh (int  k)

    {this.num=k; }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(this.num==4){
            setAge(40);
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " :"+this.num + ":" + getAge());
    }
    synchronized int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    synchronized void  setAge(int  k) {
        this.age =k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here :

1. You are using a instance variable **age** and creating a 10 instances of MyTh class so each instance will have its own copy and they will not interfere with each others operation. So as per the suggestion from @tanyehzheng you will have to make it static so that it can be shared across all the 10 instances.
2. Your question about **What difference volatile will make if we have static** :

   - **static** only states that the copy will be shared across all the instances and it doesn't guarantee memory visibility in case of multiple threads trying to update/access it.
   - **volatile** on the other hand will guarantee Memory visibility, i.e. if any write has occurred to the variable then all the subsequent read will see the latest value (happens-before relation). Which was not possible if you use only static because CPU core may cache the value or have it in register.

Comment: I see. How can i find an evidence that Threads may cache copy of static  vars ?. I print the hashcode value  to find out from where the threads are reading the static var . I found all threads printed same value . Same  like  in volatile .https://void-summary.blogspot.com/

Comment: IMHO It is actually at CPU level so you can't test it via java program. And printing hashcode will not help. I will recommend you to read [cpu-cache-flushing-fallacy](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2013/02/cpu-cache-flushing-fallacy.html) from Martin Thompson